# Building .NET Application for Different Versions of Crystal Report in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

How Can i Build a .NET Application targeting different versions or probably the lower versions of the Crystal Report in Visual Studio .

The Client Machine contains the Crystal Report 9 runtime as well as designer installed .

Now is it run a .NET Application that uses Crystal Report Components in Visual Studio 2008 / 2010 that targets Crystal Report 9 without installing any Additional Runtimes apart from the above . If yes how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can use this XML in your app.config or web.config:**

```
  <runtime> 
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="12.0.2000.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Shared" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="12.0.2000.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="12.0.2000.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="12.0.2000.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="12.0.1100.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="12.0.1100.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

in atribute "oldVersion" you have to put the version which you want to substitute for the version in the atribute "newVersion"

Comment: I wanted to use version '13.0.2000.0' on production server whereas version '10.2.3600.0' is installed on development server. But, it shows a 500 error when the above lines (with correct versions) is added in web.config. Any suggestions to get it work for me?

Comment: How do you know what is the correct publicKeyToken value?